# Firebase - auth user only within a scope

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use the firebase token as a token for my own REST-api as well - which I need in order to handle customer data/payments. While authenticated as master with the `FIREBASE_SECRET`, the only way that I know off to go from `token` to `auth` object is to use `authWithCustomToken`. However, that messes up the original firebase reference as well. Is it possible to only auth one reference - or keep the auth within that scope? This would be ideal:

```
let firebaseRef = new Firebase('https://<app>.firebaseio.com')
firebaseRef.authWithCustomToken(SECRET)
firebaseRef.authWithCustomToken(FROM_USER_REQUEST, (err, auth) => {
  // Here I could do what I want authenticated as the custom user
}, {
  scope: onlyThis
})
firebaseRef.child('adminTable').once('value', snap => {
  // This would still work, as the auth only applies to the previous block and has now reverted to admin privileges
})
```

As stated, another possibility would be to have multiple references to the firebase database, with each reference owning its own internal auth state.

Comment: The `Firebase()` constructor takes an *undocumented* extra argument that identifies the session. So if you create `var ref1 = new Firebase(url, '1'); and `var ref2 = new Firebase(url, '2');` you'll end up with two sessions. But in general if you run Firebase-accessing code on  a server, it's common to run this under admin-level credentials.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198186/firebase-authentication-limits/30201090#30201090

Comment: Absolutely, that's the thing. What I really need is to identify a user through the token. The only way to do so I believe is to call the `authWithCustomToken` with the `token` from the `request`. Thanks anyway, the session thing will definately be my rescue.