# Refer to multiple firebase database in the same project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm on an andoird project and I need to connect my app to 2 firebase databases. The problem is when i lunch the app, it crashes. I tried some suggestions i found here like: [Firebase Authentication Limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198186/firebase-authentication-limits)
but it didn't work. How can i do that please? thx in advance

```
//FIREBASE_URL is used to store data in a firebase database
private static final String FIREBASE_URL ="https://**********.firebaseio.com/";
//FIREBASE_STRING is used to read data from another firebase database
private static final String FIREBASE_STRING ="https://++++++++++++.firebaseio.com/";
private Firebase firebaseRef;
private Firebase fbRef;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    firebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
    fbRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_STRING);

}
//The app crashes when this methode
//This methode is used to read data from the second direbase database
public void itineraryListener() {
        fbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There are " + snapshot.getChildrenCount() + " locations", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Itinerary post = postSnapshot.getValue(Itinerary.class);
                }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An error occured! " + firebaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The writing methode works well, but the reading one doesn't

Comment: Without seeing the *minimal* code that reproduces the problem you have, it will be hard to help.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen i edited my question, thx for ur help

Comment: You say "The app crashes when this methode". Can you add the stack trace to the question?