# Firebase blocks all requests after registering 100 users

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I need to register many generated users in Firebase from web application. I didn't find any methods in API Reference of Firebase to do it in one request, so I call createUserWithEmailAndPassword for every generated pair email/password. After registering 100 users, I get the auth/too-many-requests error and can't send requests for 30 minutes or more because of Firebase blocking all requests from device.

How to prevent blocking my application in firebase console or what to write in code of web application for that? I'm using standart firebase connection:

```
const config = {
apiKey: 'my-api-key',
authDomain: 'my-project.firebaseapp.com',
databaseURL: 'https://my-project.firebaseio.com',
storageBucket: 'my-project.appspot.com',
messagingSenderId: 'my-sender-id'};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

And register every of 100 user with createUserWithEmailAndPassword:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

I'm calling all requests with using Promise.all

```
firebase.Promise.all(registerRequests)
```

where register request is createUserWithEmailAndPassword promise

Comment: Is this kinda like a migration procedure? Or just a usual process for your app? The [auth/too-many-requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Error) error is just a safety measure for *unusual activity* detected in apps.

Comment: @AL. It's a usual process for my app. This is a users generator that my customer needs. I know that auth/too-many-requests error is a safety measure, and I need Firebase not to block this activity. Maybe to write in Firebase console some rule for just this app or use another way to create users

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest using the Admin node.js SDK. You will have privileged access to create as many email and password users as you want without being throttled.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user

Comment: This answer I also get from Firebase technical support. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` API is meant to be used by regular users to sign up for your app. As such it has a pretty low rate limit, to prevent abuse.

If you want to bulk create users, you should use the [`auth:import` command in the Firebase CLI tools](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth-import). This is specifically made for this cause, and has no such rate limit.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem boils down to Firebase Spark limitations which state that there is only 100 simultaneous connections allowed. And when you are creating a new user you set up a new connection to the db.

> A Firebase User has a fixed set of basic properties—a unique ID, a
> primary email address, a name and a photo URL—stored in the project's
> user database, that can be updated by the user (iOS, Android, web).
>
> From [Users in Firebase project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users).

As a workaround try creating a new config after creating 100 users as stated in here [Firebase Authentication Limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198186/firebase-authentication-limits).

It also might be because each time you register a user it logs him in and retains the connection for a while. There is definitely a way to close that connection after registration.

Comment: No, reconnection doesn't help

Comment: What kind of reconnection are you doing?

Comment: firebase.app().delete().then(function() {
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
});

Comment: I don't think this counts as a reconnection.

Comment: I asked firebase technical support about my problem and get the answer that there is no frontend-way to prevent blocking. So they suggested to use Node.js Admin SDK.